# How to use QPainter to draw lines on the QScrollArea?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qpainter, qscrollarea

I'm trying to use PyQt5 to create a data structure visualization simulator. There is a QWidget and a QScrollArea inside.

```
class test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  
        ...
        ...
        self.setUI() 

    def setUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(250, 200, 1500, 750)
        self.setWindowTitle('data structure visualization simulator')

        self.topFiller = QWidget()
        self.topFiller.setMinimumSize(1200, 2000)
        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.topFiller)

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.scroll)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
```

Now I need to draw lines on the QScrollArea, what should I write in QPainter?

```
    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        pen = QPen()
        pen.setWidth(1)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawLine(15, 80, 1080, 120)
```

Answer (score 0):

The paintEvent is received by the widget that is actually going to be painted, you can't implement it from another widget, even if it's its parent; you'll need to either subclass the scrollarea and implement paintEvent from there, or intercept the event using an event filter.
In both cases, the painter target must be the scrollarea's [`viewport()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#viewport).

Subclassing:

```
class MyScrollArea(QScrollArea):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self.viewport())
        pen = QPen()
        pen.setWidth(1)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawLine(15, 80, 1080, 120)
```

Event filtering:

```
class test(QWidget):
    def setUI(self):
        # ...
        # install the event filter on the area's *viewport*
        self.scroll.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Paint:
            super().eventFilter(source, event)
            # "source" is the viewport
            qp = QPainter(source)
            pen = QPen()
            pen.setWidth(1)
            qp.setPen(pen)
            qp.drawLine(15, 80, 1080, 120)
            return False
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)
```